# Using ffmpeg shared library in a commercial C/C++ application

Tags: ffmpeg

We have a C++-based application that runs on Windows, Mac, and Linux. I now need to add h.264 and h.265 decoding within this application. It seems ffmpeg will do the trick.

As ours is a commercial application, we cannot disclose the source code to public. However, as I understand, FFMpeg is based on LGPL licensing requirements. Going through various articles on LGPL requirements, it seems I can use ffmpeg without disclosing our source code as long as:

1. I build ffmpeg as a shared libraries and make sure that I don't use "--enable-gpl" flag during configuration.
2. I acknowledge in our About dialog box that we are using ffmpeg shared libraries.

Can someone please verify if this more or less meets the requirements? Regards.

Note that I need ffmpeg only to decode and not to encode. Therefore, I don't have to use "--enable-libx264" and "--enable-libx265" flags.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As a FFmpeg developer, I would expect you to follow the considerations mentioned on our [website](https://www.ffmpeg.org/legal.html):

1. Compile FFmpeg without "--enable-gpl" and without
   "--enable-nonfree".
2. Use dynamic linking (on windows, this means
   linking to dlls) for linking with FFmpeg libraries.
3. Distribute the
   source code of FFmpeg, no matter if you modified it or not.
4. Make
   sure the source code corresponds exactly to the library binaries you
   are distributing.
5. Run the command "git diff > changes.diff" in the
   root directory of the FFmpeg source code to create a file with only
   the changes.
6. Explain how you compiled FFmpeg, for example the
   configure line, in a text file added to the root directory of the
   source code.
7. Use tarball or a zip file for distributing the source
   code.
8. Host the FFmpeg source code on the same webserver as the
   binary you are distributing.
9. Add "This software uses code of [FFmpeg](http://ffmpeg.org) licensed under the [LGPLv2.1](http://www.gnu.org/licenses/old-licenses/lgpl-2.1.html) and its source can be downloaded here [where here is a link to the source code]" to every page in your website
   where there is a download link to your application.
10. Mention "This
    software uses libraries from the FFmpeg project under the LGPLv2.1"
    in your program "about box".
11. Mention in your EULA that your program
    uses FFmpeg under the LGPLv2.1.
12. If your EULA claims ownership over
    the code, you have to explicitly mention that you do not own FFmpeg,
    and where the relevant owners can be found.
13. Remove any prohibition
    of reverse engineering from your EULA.
14. Apply the same changes to all
    translations of your EULA.
15. Do not misspell FFmpeg (two capitals F
    and lowercase "mpeg").
16. Do not rename FFmpeg dlls to some obfuscated
    name, but adding a suffix or prefix is fine (renaming "avcodec.dll"
    to "MyProgDec.dll" is not fine, but to "avcodec-MyProg.dll" is).
17. Go
    through all the items again for any LGPL external library you
    compiled into FFmpeg (for example LAME).
18. Make sure your program is
    not using any GPL libraries (notably libx264).

From what you've said so far, I think you're doing only point 1-2, 9-11, 15-18. You need to make the source code (of FFmpeg) including modifications (3-5, 7-8) available along with your application, mention build instructions (6), remove ownership claims on FFmpeg, remove reverse engineering prohibitions (if any), and check your EULA (12-14).

Comment: Hi Ronald. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: hi, if i made custom "h264dec.h" for Hardware-based decoder, and use it for commercial application. then is it illegal?

Comment: Adding extra API is allowed under LGPL (in fact, modifications are encouraged). As long as you publish your modifications to the library, I think it would be fine. If you're unsure, ask a lawyer :).

Comment: Thanks for the info! Currently, feeding RTSP packet (via ffmpeg) to our HW decoder,  decoded frame flickering.

Comment: fixed some bugs for my  application: my ffmpeg library: https://github.com/sailfish009/ffmpeg and application: https://github.com/sailfish009/sample_decode

Comment: am I allowed to use binary file (static linking) in Android application (apk) and providing user an option to set its own path to any FFmpeg binary file he wants (to use it instead of mine)?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, with lgpl you can use it as a dll/shared lib and you won't need to make your source code available.
But you should be aware that it's not the licensing of the **code** is the issue for commercial use, but the patents around h.264/h.265 and you need license for that. AFAIK, even if you simply want to decode you'll still need to have license.

MPEGLA is the licensing body for h264 codec patent pool.

Comment: Pavel. Thank you for your help. It appears H264 as well as H265 licensing is only for encoding, not for decoding.

Comment: @Peter I'm pretty sure it's not as simple as that. Do you think all blue-ray player manufacturers do not pay licensing fees to be able to decode h264 encoded videos? For that same reason chromium doesn't have h264 capabilities.